# Design disappear when create button Android

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am creating the registration page where is created a button but the issue is the button is not placing if I comment the code for that button all other design is starting showing in the design section but if is un-comment the code for the button the design disappear and the black screen started showing

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bb">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputUsername"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputUsername"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputUsername"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputUsername" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_security"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="******"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputEmail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputEmail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputEmail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputConformPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_security"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="******"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputPassword"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputPassword" />

<!--    <Button-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="0dp"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"-->
<!--        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"-->
<!--        android:text="Register"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputConformPassword"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputConformPassword"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputConformPassword" />-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alreadyHaveAccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/colorwhite"
        android:text="Already Have an Account?"
        android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnRegister"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnRegister"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnRegister" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I tried the above same xml , it is working if i uncomment also , make sure u have all the drawables , color code available, check if error is available

Comment: No there is no error showing

Comment: Added design image in url : https://ibb.co/Qm5GcPt for verifying

Comment: So why its not working for me just the button creating problem without button all design is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by just making `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`
from Values>Themes>Themes.xml. By doing this the problem solved for me